# What's the best way to compile a C# library for .NET 3.5 and 4.5.1

Tags: c#, compilation, .net-3.5, .net-4.5

We need to build our system for both .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.5.1 Our system is a reporting engine composed of a bunch of DLLs. Many of our customers are still on the .NET 2.0 runtime, hence we must have a .NET 2.0 version.

However, we also need to have 2 optional DLLs that require .NET 4.0, one for the OData API and one for the new Oracle connector. Both of these require the .NET 4.0 runtime.

Is there a way to use the existing solution & project files and from the command line tell it to build for 3.5 or 4.5.1? Or do we need to duplicate all the solution & project files?

thanks - dave

Comment: You can edit the project file and change the target framework based on configuration.

Comment: For similar situations, I've just updated the .csproj/.vbproj file and replaced the .NET version used. Then just reload the project and compile. If you want to make it very easy, you can just have a batch script to do these replacements.